# Display all posts published before x post when viewing single.php

Tags: php, wordpress

A user clicks on a post that was published on 12th March 2012 (for example) they get taken to single.php where the content of that post is displayed as normal.

Beneath this content I would like to display all posts published before it, not after. So, taking my example above, all posts published after the 12th March will not be displayed. You will only see all posts before that date. Can anyone help me edit my existing loop to do this? Here's my working loop that currently displays all posts, no matter what the date:

```
<!-- Show all posts within this category -->
                <div id="post-wrap">
                <?php
                $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                $args= array(
                    'category_name' => 'offsite', 
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'posts_per_page' => 1
                );
                query_posts($args);
                if( have_posts() ) :?>

                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                <article>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <span>/ <?php the_time('l jS F') ?></span></a></h1>

                    <?php the_content(''); ?>

                    <div class="a-options">
                        <a href="#new" class="comments scrollto">Comment</a>

                        <!-- share -->
                            <div class="share-button">
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <div class="facebook">                          

                                        <div class="fb-like" data-href="www.MyKettlesYard.co.uk" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="95" data-show-faces="false" data-font="Arial"></div>

                                        <span class="child-pseudo">Facebook</span>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="twitter">

                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="www.MyKettlesYard.co.uk" data-text="Kettles Yard, Cambridge - www.MyKettlesYard.co.uk" data-count="horizontal">Tweet</a><script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

                                        <span class="child-pseudo">Twitter</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <span class="pseudo-button">&#043; Share</span>
                             </div> <!--! /share -->

                    </div><!--! /a-options -->

                    <?php global $withcomments;
                    $withcomments = 1;
                    comments_template(); ?>

                  </article>


                <?php endwhile; ?>

                    <div id="next-prev-wrap" class="nextprev"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts /', $post->max_num_pages ); ?> <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts', $post->max_num_pages ); ?></div>

                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your code (listed above) create a variable for the current post date

```
$current_post_date = $post->post_date;
```

Then inside your loop, wrap your output in an if statement

```
if($post->post_date < $current_post_date)
{
   //show your posts
}
```

Comment: Awesome, so simple! Cheers Nick!